# in PayPal, is it possible to do checkout with normal button, not paypal button?

Tags: php, api, button, paypal, checkout

I am using PayPal Rest API, and I make PHP page that let buyers do payment.

I make code from this link - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/

So I made 'Buy Now' button like this code:

```
    <div id="paypal-button"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        style: {
            color: 'blue',
            size: 'large',
            shape: 'rect',
            label: 'buynow',
        },

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            alert('1');
            /* 
            * Set up the payment here 
            */
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            alert('2');
            /* 
            * Execute the payment here 
            */
        },

        onCancel: function(data, actions) {
            alert('3');
            /* 
            * Buyer cancelled the payment 
            */
        },

        onError: function(err) {
            alert('4');
            /* 
            * An error occurred during the transaction 
            */
        }
        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
```

But actually payment should be done when click other normal button, not this paypal button. (This is related with my logic.)

So when click that normal button, paypal payment should be done.

- I thought it can be done by triggering click event of paypal button.

But it seems not so simple to do that.
I see paypal button is in iframe with different domain. It makes hard to trigger any event.

- So I thought one another way to do this - when click payment button, doing payment from server-side. And it returns paypal checkout page url to redirect. and open new small window manually from this paypal checkout page url.

It is from this link - http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

and code is like this

```
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $item_1 = new Item();
    $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice($amountVal); /** unit price **/

    $shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();
    $shipping_address->setCity('San Jose');
    $shipping_address->setCountryCode('US');
    $shipping_address->setPostalCode('95132');
    $shipping_address->setLine1('My St');
    $shipping_address->setState('CA');
    $shipping_address->setRecipientName('Recipient1');

    $billing_address = new Address();
    $billing_address->setCity('San Jose');
    $billing_address->setCountryCode('US');
    $billing_address->setPostalCode('95132');
    $billing_address->setLine1('My St2');
    $billing_address->setState('CA');

    $payer_info = new PayerInfo();
    $payer_info->setBillingAddress($billing_address);
    $payer_info->setEmail('a@2.com');
    $payer->setPayerInfo($payer_info);

    $item_list = new ItemList();
    $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));
    $item_list->setShippingAddress($shipping_address);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal($amountVal);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($item_list)
        ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

    $payee_email = Input::get('payee');
    if ($payee_email) {
        $payee = new Payee();
        $payee->setEmail($payee_email);
        $transaction->setPayee($payee);
    }

    $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(url('paypal/status')) /** Specify return URL **/
        ->setCancelUrl(url('paypal/status'));

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('Sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
        ->setExperienceProfileId($profile_id)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create(PaypalController::$_api_context);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        return json_decode($ex->getData());
        return 'Error: ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
        }
    }

    /** add payment ID to session **/
    Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());
    if (isset($redirect_url)) {
    /** redirect to paypal **/
        return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
    }

    return 'Unknown error occurred';
```

It is working something, but after call this server side function, when I open new small window for paypal checkout, background is not faded like when click normal paypal button.

Fading means fading backgrounds with string 'Don't see the secure PayPal browser? We'll help you re-launch the window to complete your purchase. ...'. Maybe you can know.

So it seems not so secure.

Finally so I want to know 2 things.

1. If I want to do paypal payment when click non-paypal button, how can I do this?
2. Is there any way to fade background with 'Don't see the secure PayPal browser? We'll help you re-launch the window to complete your purchase. ...' manually when open new paypal checkout page by clicking non-paypal button?

Thanks much to anyone help!

Comment: If it is a `REST` `API` you do — not — want to ask that question. Since it isn‘t the answer is yes.

Comment: 1 and 2 are all 'no'?

Comment: @AjAX. Is there any way to do this without REST API?

Comment: No. Look into the docs. It is very easy. I am just saying. This is no `REST` `API`.

Comment: @AjAX.. which document is very easy and no REST API?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/.

Comment: can you let me know detailed part of this document about doing these 2 things without REST API?

Comment: There is no `REST API`. Just an `API`. That is why it is so complicated and easy.

Comment: @AjAX., https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/?mark=REST%20API This page says about `REST API`.

Comment: They call it `REST`. But it isn't. Just do as they say. Love.

Comment: @AjAX. Thanks for your response.